# WPF application doesn't run in another folder

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, visual-studio-community

My OS  is windows 10 and I have a WPF project (dot net 4.6.2 , visual studio community 2017) that runs in release and debug mode without any problem.
also i can run it from release or debug folder from my project folder.
but when i copy release or debug folder to any other place in my computer , my application runs and show wait cursor and nothing more.
my application doesn't need to any source from outside of my project.

Comment: Tried to start as administrator?

Comment: yes run as administrator didn't work

Comment: Tried to attach to debug version in copied folder?

Comment: copy all dll files to the new folder

Comment: u have probably a link to a file/directory inside the release/debug! check all the resources for links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was a problem to set the icon path when I set it for 
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.

I created a folder with '**Content**' name in my project And then put the icon file inside it.

in xaml , I set window icon "/Content/Icon.ico" and it worked.

for NotifyIcon i set Icon "../../Content/Icon.ico"
that it also worked but when I Copy Release folder to another dorectory it didn't work.

So I drag the icon file in Resources and I set the icon of NotifyIcon like this:

```
 new Icon(Resources.AppIcon,40,40);
```

This error occurred because I'm confused about how to address the files in WPF.